# LINQ decimal value in query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mongodb, linq

I use:

- Asp.net core
- MongoDB Driver 2.4.2

I'm building a Mongo DB Linq query like hereunder:

This returns records as expected:

```
int.TryParse("1", out intVal);
query = query.Where(x => x.MyIntField == intVal);
```

This doesn't return any records while there are records that have MyDecimalField equal to 1.0:

```
decimal.TryParse("1.0", out decVal);
query = query.Where(x => x.MyDecimalField == decVal);
```

Does anybody have a clue why?

Comment: What is the decimal separator of your current culture? Always use the returned `bool` from `TryParse`, otherwise you might not notice that the parse process failed and you compare with the default value which is `0` for numeric types.

Comment: Is the database returning a string or an decimal?  You cannot parse a decimal to a decimal.  Only string can be parsed.  if number is already a number do not parse.

Comment: Where is the `"1.0"` bit coming from? I'm assuming you haven't actually hardcoded `"1.0"` in your code, as it would make no sense to parse it. You could simply set `var decVal = 1.0M;`.

Comment: One thing that can help debugging is that you can cast your queryable to `MongoQueryable<T>` which then has a method on it `GetMongoQuery()` which returns a `BsonDocument` of the query. You can then analyze this (I find just doing a `ToString()` on it makes it readable) to see the difference between your two queries. This is using version 1.11 of the drivers.

Comment: Did you check into all has value. Just hard code value and check query

Answer (score 2):

There can be two problems

First problem can be in your culture. Decimal separator in your culture is not `.` (maybe it is `,`).

You can use decimal separator which your culture uses.

```
var parsed = decimal.TryParse("1,0", out decVal); // instead of "," use your culture decimal separator

if (parsed)
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.MyDecimalField == decVal);
}
```

Or try to use `InvariantCulture`:

```
var parsed = decimal.TryParse("1.0", NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out decVal);

if (parsed)
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.MyDecimalField == decVal);
}
```

The second problem can be in parsing some text that cannot be parsed to `decimal`. If this text cannot be parsed then default value of `decVal` is `0` and filter by `Where` doesn't return values with `MyDecimalField == 0`.

You need to check if value is parsed and if it is then you can query some data.